# Переход к объявлению в Atom

Tags: java, atom

Кто-нибудь пробовал редактор [атом](https://atom.io/) на windows 7?
Как настроить "Go to declaration"? У меня полностью отказывается работать.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал. Установил этот редактор.

1. Сгенерировать файл меток.
2. Создать репозиторий git для проекта.
3. Добавить каталог проекта в дерево проекта в редакторе. Проверить: по ctrl-p у тебя будут доступны файлы из проекта.

По тегам переходит.

Проверь, может у тебя не там лежит файл меток? Думаю, он должен находиться в корне проекта, который ты добавляешь.